# equilibrium state of a system in statistical mechanics

Tags: statistical-mechanics

Why we consider the maximum number of micro states or complexions as equilibrium state of a macro state or a system in statistical physics?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In statistical mechanics all micro-states are considered to be equally likely. This means that the most likely macro-state is the one that contains the most micro-states. This macro-state is considered at equilibrium because one the system is there, it is unlikely to move away from that macro state, as the vast majority of micro-states are contained in that macro-state.